# Ubuntu 16.04 Volume Notification keeps popping up

Tags: sound, notification

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and also new to this forum so I'm sorry if my question isn't very clear.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 last weekend and after 4/5 days of successful running my system has now started displaying the volume notification randomly (its probably every 5/10 seconds). When listening to music the volume appears to very briefly change and then revert back to where it has been set.

At first i thought this could be something to do with my media keys on my wireless keyboard however I unplugged the keyboard and and it continued to happen.

It's becoming really annoying! Does anyone have any ideas about how I could resolve it, even if its just a temporary work around.

Thanks
Nick

Comment: It's a Bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1585084

Comment: Hi Hizqeel, thanks for that. Hopefully it gets fixed quickly!