# Ubuntu 16.04 disable notification bubbles (for pulseaudio)

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, notification, notify-osd

Regarding [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793738/ubuntu-16-04-volume-notification-keeps-popping-up), respectively [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1585084):

Is there actually a workaround to fix it. It annoyed me for quite some time now and at this point I don't even care, if I had to disable the notifications for pulseaudio for good. Although fixes of a different kind are very welcome as well.

Comment: Did you upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 and the problem wasn't there? I had some problems after upgrading where every time I suspended sound switched from TV to laptop but fixed that with sleep overrides but I never had the bubble battles you have. If things were better in an older version I'd try to downgrade to that version. I had to downgrade Conky from 1.10 to 1.9 after 16.04 upgrade. Sorry not a PulseAudio expert.

Comment: Well, there is [notifyosdconfig](http://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications) to basically make every notification invisible. However I'm using redshift and every time the bubble appears the screen flickers for a fraction of a second, which is maddening when watching videos in fullscreen, so I thought its best to turn them off all together.

Comment: I don't know what redshift is. Funny thing is I don't recall getting any notifications refuarding sound. Only when pressing volume up or down keys a volume level indicator briefly pops up and that is probably Ubuntu not Pulse Audio. Hopefully others sharing your problem can share solutions.